# Google Speech API returns empty result for some FLAC files, and not for the others although they have same codec and sample rate

Tags: python, ffmpeg, google-speech-api

Below code is what I used to make request for transcription.

```
import io
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
def transcribe_file(speech_file):
    """Transcribe the given audio file."""

    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    encoding = speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC
    if os.path.splitext(speech_file)[1] == ".wav":
        encoding = speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16
    with io.open(speech_file, "rb") as audio_file:
        content = audio_file.read()

    audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
    config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
        sample_rate_hertz=32000,
        language_code="ja-JP",
        max_alternatives=3,
        enable_word_time_offsets=True,
        enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
        enable_word_confidence=True,
    )

    response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)
    #print(speech_file, "Recognition Done")
    return response
```

As I wrote in title, the results of response has empty list for some files, and not for some files.
They have same sample rate and codec(32000, FLAC)

Below is the result of `ffprobe -i "AUDIOFILE" -show_streams` for one of each cases.

Left one is empty one. The only difference is duration of file.

How can I get non empty results?

[Result of ffprobe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PwJG.png)

Edit:

[Result of ffprobe show stream show format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqXet.png)

[Something not captured in one screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ue2M.png)

Sadly, re-mux didn't work.

I used ffmpeg-git-20210225

ffbrobe result of broken one

```
./ffprobe -show_streams -show_format broken.flac 
ffprobe version N-56320-ge937457b7b-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 66.100 / 56. 66.100
  libavcodec     58.125.101 / 58.125.101
  libavformat    58. 68.100 / 58. 68.100
  libavdevice    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavfilter     7.107.100 /  7.107.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, flac, from 'broken.flac':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:00.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 342 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 32000 Hz, mono, s16
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=flac
codec_long_name=FLAC (Free Lossless Audio Codec)
profile=unknown
codec_type=audio
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=s16
sample_rate=32000
channels=1
channel_layout=mono
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/32000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=28672
duration=0.896000
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=16
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=broken.flac
nb_streams=1
nb_programs=0
format_name=flac
format_long_name=raw FLAC
start_time=0.000000
duration=0.896000
size=38362
bit_rate=342517
probe_score=100
TAG:encoder=Lavf58.45.100
[/FORMAT]
```

ffprobe result of non_broken one

```
./ffprobe -show_streams -show_format non_broken.flac 
ffprobe version N-56320-ge937457b7b-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 66.100 / 56. 66.100
  libavcodec     58.125.101 / 58.125.101
  libavformat    58. 68.100 / 58. 68.100
  libavdevice    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavfilter     7.107.100 /  7.107.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, flac, from 'non_broken.flac':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:00.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 358 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 32000 Hz, mono, s16
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=flac
codec_long_name=FLAC (Free Lossless Audio Codec)
profile=unknown
codec_type=audio
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=s16
sample_rate=32000
channels=1
channel_layout=mono
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/32000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=27648
duration=0.864000
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=16
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=non_broken.flac
nb_streams=1
nb_programs=0
format_name=flac
format_long_name=raw FLAC
start_time=0.000000
duration=0.864000
size=38701
bit_rate=358342
probe_score=100
TAG:encoder=Lavf58.45.100
[/FORMAT]
```

And the result of `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i sine=d=0.864:r=32000 output.flac`

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'sine=d=0.864:r=32000':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 512 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, mono, s16, 512 kb/s
File 'output.flac' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> flac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, flac, to 'output.flac':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 32000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 flac
[Parsed_sine_0 @ 0x55c317ddda00] EOF timestamp not reliable
size=      16kB time=00:00:00.86 bitrate= 154.0kbits/s speed= 205x    
video:0kB audio:8kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 99.364586%
```

Comment: @llogan I'm sorry. It seems hard to provide file itself because of copyright. Any other information to use instead?

Comment: Only blind guesses. Show the **complete** output of `ffprobe -show_streams -show_format input.flac` for both files. Does it work if you re-mux? `ffmpeg -i broken.flac -c copy output.flac`

Comment: @llogan I upload capture of ```ffprobe -show_streams -show_format``` of both files, and re-muxed file also returns empty resutls.

Comment: [Get a recent ffmpeg](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) (git master, not release) and try re-muxing both the working and not working file to rule out muxing issue. Try making a synthetic file: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i sine=d=0.864:r=32000 output.flac` Lame suggestions but not much to work with here.

Comment: @llogan I tried ```ffmpeg -i broken.flac -c copy output.flac``` with recent ffmpeg, but it didn't work for broken file, fine with non_broken one. I'm not sure this is what you intended, I tried ```ffmpeg -f lavfi -i sine=d=0.864:r=32000 -i input.flac output.flac``` to both files(broken, non_broken), but it didn't work with broken one, and even non_broken one returns with empty results. If it's not what you intended sorry, I couldn't figure out what "Try making a synthetic file" means.

Comment: I meant that you can make ffmpeg generate a sine wave and output a flac for testing. Command is literally `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i sine=d=0.864:r=32000 output.flac`. But it's moot. Now I realize the google API is probably not having any issue with the file or the muxing or format (with no errors provided it's what I assumed by default), but the problem is probably with the actual content. Your files are so short, are you sure the non working files even have any audible content for the API to recognize?

Comment: @llogan I can guarantee that it has some audible contents. I'm trying to make transcript of files by hand. So, I checked it has proper contents. Most of other short length(<1sec) files are working fine. 
I think maybe the reason some files(with  more length, there are not woking files with 3~5 sec length too) could be the STT issue(like voca?)